# Taking user input from a form, showing it on a website in an array, and replacing variety of the strings with different words

Tags: javascript, arrays

First time here, and I am lost. Hoping for some help with this.

I want to take a user number in a form and output in HTML as an array. Then take that array and slice different strings based on the number. Similar to the fizz bzz, but a few more steps.

This is in javascript but I am so lost and I have been working on it for a week.

Please help.

```js
function robotSpeaks(number) {
  let output = [];
  for (i = 0; i <=number; i++){
    //pseudo code - 1 - need to push out an array of numbers
    // 2 Splice out the numbers
    // 3 return the code with beep, boop, wont you be my neighbor
    output.push(i);

  }
}

$(document).ready(function(){
  $("#numberInput").submit(function(event){
    event.preventDefault();
    let numberInput = $("#numberInput").val();
    let output =robotSpeaks(number);
    output.forEach(function(element){
      $("#robotSpoke").append("<li>" + element + "</li>");
    });
  });
});
```

```html
<div class="container">
      <div class="jumbotron">
        <h2>Mr. Roboger's Neighborhood</h2>
        <form id='robogerForm'>
          <label for="number">Enter a number, I am a robot... Beep! Boop!</label>
          <input type="number" id="numberInput">
      </div>
          <input type="button" type="submit" value="Compute to Robot Speak"></button>
        </form>
        <ul id ="robotSpoke"></ul>
      </div>
    </div>
```

Here is my current code -
[jsfiddle.net/wattsjmichael/wtfnua4j/1](http://jsfiddle.net/u2v5paf1/)

Comment: You should include the code you are trying to make work in your question.

Comment: Sorry about that. Here you go!